# Usar una variable desde un javascript externo a mi plantilla blade para un slider con owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, laravel, slider, twitter

Vuelvo a ustedes para solicitar su valiosa ayuda y guía, después de mucho buscar encontré la forma de traer los tweet de Twitter como yo quiero y no como Twitter me lo quiere dar, todo esto usando laravel con blade y jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher, ahora quiero armar un slider pero los eventos javascript y estilos css no me funcionan supongo porque armo el contenedor desde el JS, así que supongo que tendré que pasar los tweets de alguna forma a la plantilla para poder hacer un foreach

les dejo el código para que me puedan entender, para traer los tweets estoy usando jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher

```
var configProfile = {
  "profile": {"screenName": 'Binance_Spanish'},
  "domId": 'exampleProfile',
  "maxTweets": 3,
  "enableLinks": true, 
  "showUser": true,
  "showTime": true,
  "showImages": false,
  "lang": 'en',
  "dataOnly": true,
  "customCallback": populateTpl
};
twitterFetcher.fetch(configProfile);

function populateTpl(tweets){
  var element = document.getElementById('oc-testi');
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0, lgth = tweets.length; i < lgth ; i++) {
    var tweetObject = tweets[i];
    html += '<div class="owl-item active"">'
            +' <div class="oc-item">'
                +'<div class="testimonial">'
                  +'<div class="testi-image">'
                    + (tweetObject.image ? '<div class="tweet-img"><img src="'+tweetObject.image+'" /></div>' : '')
                  +'</div>'
                  +'<div class="testi-content">'
                    + '<p >' + tweetObject.tweet + '</p>'
                    + '<p >Posted on the ' + tweetObject.time + ', by ' + tweetObject.author + '</p>'
                    +' <div class="testi-meta">'
                      + '<p ><a href="' + tweetObject.permalinkURL + '">Link</a></p>'
                    +'</div>'
                  +'</div>'
                + '</div>'
            +'</div>'
            +'</div>'
  }

  element.innerHTML = html;

  
}
```

Y así armo mi plantilla

```
<h2>Profile Example without using widget ID (New Twitter Change)</h2>
<div id="oc-testi"  class="owl-carousel testimonials-carousel">
    <div class="owl-stage-outer"></div>
    <div id="oc-testi1" class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0s ease 0s; width: 1933.34px;">

    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var ocTesti = $("#oc-testi");

        ocTesti.owlCarousel({
            margin: 20,
            nav: true,
            navText: ['<i class="icon-angle-left"></i>','<i class="icon-angle-right"></i>'],
            dots: true,
            responsive:{
                0:{ items:1 },
                768:{ items:2 },
                992:{ items:3 }
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Asi se ve el resultado, como pueden ver los eventos no funcionan, no se ven las flechas de prev y next, y me muestra 4 ítems aunque le coloque el máximo serian 3, y no funciona lo visual del carrusel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por eso creo que es mejor armar el slider en mi plantilla usando los datos desde el JS, que en todo caso seria una forma de pasar el array de $tweets a mi plantilla html.

Agradecere toda la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Parece que el problema es que estás tratando de activar `Owl Carousel` cuando todavía no tiene contenido. Intenta colocar ese código debajo de esta línea: `element.innerHTML = html;`

Comment: Excelente amigo Triby, asi si cargo todos los eventos muchisimas gracias ojala pudiera indicar tu respuesta como la correcta y darte puntos.